# How can I have chain links collide with other chain links, except for their overlapping neighbours?

Tags: matter.js

The oft-cited chains demo (specifically the third chain made of polygons) can serve as a minimal example of a non-working solution:
https://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#chains
I would like each link in the chain to be able to collide with other *non-neighbouring* links.

That is, all bodies must collide with all other bodies, unless they share at least one constraint.

Though I have not used it, this appears to be the default behaviour of *box2D* through the use of `collideConnected`
"Joint definition" from [box2D documentation](https://box2d.org/documentation/md__d_1__git_hub_box2d_docs_dynamics.html):

> You can specify user data for any joint type and you can provide a flag to prevent the attached bodies from colliding with each other. This is actually the default behavior and you must set the collideConnected Boolean to allow collision between to connected bodies.
> [(see the flag's definition)](https://box2d.org/documentation/structb2_joint_def.html#aef099a1f89b64e230173b6016848ea9b)

I cannot use categories and masking because I have the possibility of over 32 links.
The only solution I can think of so far is patching the logic in `Detector.canCollide`, to not collide if the bodies share a constraint, which would be sub-optimal!

Comment: Maybe the [car demo](https://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#car) is what you want. Non-colliding bodies are tied together with axles.

Comment: Hi, @ggorlen, I have already seen that demo, and am beyond recreating that. What I cannot achieve is, within that example, to attach another body to the wheel and have that body collide with the car body and other wheel. The demo puts all bodies in the same group
https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/ce03208c5f597d4a5bceaf133cc959c428dd5147/examples/car.js#L112
which would not work in my situation, as I explained. To labour the point further, if those wheels ever came into contact with one another, they would not collide, which is not what I want.

Comment: You should be able to set filters so that each wheel collides with any other wheel but not with the body of the car (links in the chain). A [mcve] showing your current attempt and use case would make it easier to provide a solution. Otherwise, I have to guess what you want and probably wind up spending a lot of time on a solution that isn't even appropriate. Showing a detector solution would also be useful so we have a baseline to improve upon.

Comment: Here is a minimal example: https://codepen.io/phunanon/pen/MWPVQKN?editors=0010
The constraints are long to allow the boxes A and C to come into contact.
Boxes A and C do not collide, which I want them to do. Basically, this is the collision "truth table" I'm after: AB false, BC false, AC true. My question could be reduced down to this, ignoring constraints.

Comment: And, concerning the chains demo: https://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#chains
I need a solution where each link of the chain does not collide with its neighbours, but can with any other link in the chain.

Comment: Thanks--can you [edit] the snippet into the question? External links can go down over time. As mentioned, I think the best solution is to use intermediate bodies in the chain, which is effectively what the car demo does. The chain demo can't collide the directly linked bodies because they'd spaz out uncontrollably unless the constraints were lengthened. In your example, make all of your bodies colliding and turn the long constraints into bodies, then link them with axles. Maybe there's a clever mask approach to give each pair a non-colliding mask, but I can't think of anything at the moment.

Comment: I know that the links cannot collide with their _neighbours_ because they would go crazy. But my problem is each chain link should collide with every other chain link bar 1-2 (its neighbours, which it overlaps with). I think I will edit my question to focus exactly on the chain example, to not be distracted by the minimal example I gave earlier.

Comment: I think I'm just repeating myself. Do you understand my suggestion above, using the car and 0-length constraints to effectively alternate collisions between links? Could you confirm or deny whether this would work for your use case?

Comment: No, that would not work in my case. My N number of links (bodies) all overlap with one another, and the constraints are of zero length, like the polygon chain in the chains demo. But to make link A not collide with link B, they must share a negative collision group, meaning link C would not collide with link A. The alternative is to use categories and masks, but I have a possibility of over 32 links. I still do not know the alternative beyond hacking Detector.canCollide to otherwise prevent collision if there are no shared constraints. I have edited my question.